# How I can use a list of a string array in JavaScript into blade view?

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I have `$dates` array which contains these elements `2020-07-04, 2020-07-05, 2020-07-05, 2020-07-01`.

And I am using Chart.js to view graph into my view. So I would like to insert this array into `labels`.

I used `@json($dates2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` but the problem was that all elements was showing in the first column (as shown in the photo below).

[image]

This my code:

```
@php ($dates = [])
    @php ($dates2 = [])

    @foreach ($samples as $sample)
        <p class="hide">{{ $date = substr($sample->created_at,0,10)}}</p>
        @php ($dates[] =$date)
    @endforeach
    <p>My array:</p>
    <p>{{ $dates2 = implode(', ', $dates) }}</p>
    <script>
        new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            // labels:  [{{ implode(', ', $dates) }}],
            labels:  [@json($dates2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)],
            datasets: [{ 
                data: [86,114,106,106],
                label: "Last 90 Days",
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false
            },
            ]
        },
       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wrapping the labels json in an extra set of brackets `[]`.

Assuming `dates2` is a normal array of strings, the `@json` template directive will output something that looks like this:

```js
["2020-07-04","2020-07-05","2020-07-05","2020-07-01"]
```

Which means you should change your labels to:

```js
labels:  @json($dates2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
```

You can verify this by looking at the actual HTML source code of your page.  The output should look like this:

```js
labels: ["2020-07-04","2020-07-05","2020-07-05","2020-07-01"]
```